# Most DRY Approach for Rails App with Lots of Subtotaling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that keeps count of User, Comments for many Movie_Categories. The models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie_category

  has_many :comments
end

class MovieCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies  
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I can of course find User's Comments count by MovieCategory doing something like this for each MovieCategory:

```
@user.comment.where("movie_category_id =?", movie_category_id)
```

However, it puts a lot of load on the server, if I need to make this call too frequently, so I was thinking about doing the calculation once per hour (in a background job) for all Users for all Movie_Categories and then storing the counts in the User table, each Movie Category with it's own column.  That way, I don't have to run the calculations for each user as frequently and can just access the counts from the User table.

The thing I'm wondering is if there is a more dry way to do this since I'm not sure when my Movie_Categories will stop growing (and with each time comes a new table field).  I also thought about caching the User show views (where these counts appear), but even so, if I don't have these columns in the User table then it seems like each time a new User page is loaded (or cached expired) it will have to run through calculating all of this for the User comment counts again.

Is there a better approach for the issue that I'm facing with not putting too much burden on the server?

Comment: Is it putting a lot of load on the server because there are many records in those tables? Do you have indexes set up for that query? It seems like a reasonable query.

Comment: Right now, it's not putting too much load because the app isn't live.  I'm just thinking about what it looks like if you have 100 or more categories and a few hundred thousand users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comments about being in development at the moment, I would say don't worry about it until you have to worry about it! However, if you want to plan ahead my suggestions would be to go with [fragment caching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html) and indexes on the foreign keys.

If your site grows to the size you're talking about, running migrations to add additional fields to your users table could take significant time.

I note you've referred to caching in your question so assume you're broadly familiar with it but given a view such as:

```
<ul>
  <li>Action Movies: 23 Comments</li>
  <li>Comedy Movies: 14 Comments</li>
</ul>
```

You would wrap this in a `cache` block:

```
<% cache "user-#{user.id}-comments", @user.comments.last.created_at.to_i  do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This will cache the fragment displaying the counts and auto expire it each time a new comment is posted by that user. You could really get into granular detail by caching each `<li>` and expiring only when a comment is posted in that category but it might be overkill at an early stage.

For the index on the foreign keys, you can add this in a migration using the syntax:

```
add_index :comments, :movie_category_id
```

I don't think the query you run is *that bad* but you never know until you hit production and scale quite what effect it will have.